# XIO: fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0" after 235 requests (235 known processed) with 0 events remaining

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pygame

Yes other people have asked this question before, but not in the same context or to my satisfaction. So, here goes::

I am writing an application using python, the program using pygame (ergo opengl) to display the graphics. The graphics are generated in the program itself (so no directory issues whatsoever).

The application also needs to access the input parallely from a user. To achieve this I use a multiprocessing block with a pipe and read the input key using pygame event loop. The below code runs in a loop. The first loop iteration works fine, but on the 2nd iteration I am thrown that XIO error.

```
   parent, child = Pipe(duplex=True)
   # this function draws the canvas
   switches, retOrient = self.drawCanvas(cond, count, dispSize, moves)
   # this function gets the user input in another thread - stage 1
   p = Process(target=userInput, args=(self.button, child) )
   p.start()
   b_press = parent.recv()
   parent.close()

def userInput(button, child):
    button_pressed = button.blockAndWait()
    child.send( "%s"%(button_pressed.keyname) )
    child.close()
```

I am a little perplexed at how this error occurs, what are the internals in XIO that cause it. None of the other answers actually explain the root cause of this error. Considering it works fine as a single process application, the multiprocessing module is closing some IO channel (the input registered object, the display object or the event loop) or opening some unnecessary channels. How can I decipher what exactly is causing this XIO error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not necessarily a real answer, but I would not use `multiprocessing` to parallelize access to sockets like the connection to the X server.  That looks like a bad idea.  Use regular threads instead.

Be aware that `multiprocessing` is a hack based (sometimes) on forking, so what exactly occurs with a forked socket when both the parent and the child try to access it... is random mixed garbage.

EDIT: the reason is that both forked sockets are still the "same end" of the socket, with the X server holding on the "other end".  When the X server wants to send a message, it writes, say, 100 bytes on the socket.  But if you're unlucky, the forked process 1 reads the first 50 bytes and the forked process 2 reads the remaining 50 bytes.  Each process is unexpectedly getting only a random part of the message.  They will each complain that the X server is sending nonsense.

Comment: +1. Many devs don't realize that X11 is built on top of sockets, so even if they know not to directly use a socket on both sides of a `fork`, they expect to be able to use the same X connection on both sides. (That being said, the most popular non-socket GUIs also don't work with `multiprocessing`, for different reasons—no CoreFoundation in forked processes on Mac, no `fork` and therefore no sharing of per-process resources like GDI on Windows…)

Comment: 1. Python threads are not exactly concurrent and that is the reason I am using multiprocessing. 
2. I was thinking along the lines of isolating the effects and opening channels (sockets or otherwise) per thread (or process). Here I don't know which channels are causing problems to isolate the effect. I was hoping on some light along this directions.
Also, could you please elaborate on why directly using a socket on both sides of a fork is a bad idea

Comment: Edited my answer.  To fix your problem, you should make very sure that any use of `multiprocessing` is restricted to the non-GUI parts of the program.  In other words, it's fine to use `multiprocessing` when you want to do computationally intensive tasks, but you must only use the API provided in the `multiprocessing` module to communicate between the various parts.  Any calls to pygame must be done from the main process.